# Angularjs websocket service memory leak

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

In my project I have an angular factory which will take care of the websocket connection with a c++ app.

Structure of the websocket factory:

```
.factory('SocketFactory', function ($rootScope) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.connect = function () {
        if(factory.ws) { return; }

        var ws = new WebSocket('ws://...');

        ws.onopen = function () {
            console.log('Connection to the App established');
        };

        ws.onerror = function () {
            console.log('Failed to established the connection to the App');
        };

        ws.onclose = function () {
            console.log('Connection to the App closed');
        };

        ws.onmessage = function (message) {
            //do stuff here
        };
        factory.ws = ws;
    };

    factory.send = function (msg) {
        if(!factory.ws){ return; }
        if(factory.ws.readyState === 1) {
            factory.ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
        }
    };

    return factory;
});
```

The c++ app will be sending images via websockets and they will be shown in a canvas that will be updated everytime a new image is received.

Everything works fine, however as soon as I start sending images to the browser, I noticed in ubuntu's system resource monitor that the memory used by chrome process keeps increasing +/-5mb each time `ws.onMessage` is fired (approximately).

I commented the code inside `ws.onMessage` leaving just the event detection and nothing else and the memory used still increases, if I comment the whole `ws.onMessage` event the memory used stays inside normal limits.

Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem? Is this happening because I should be using `$destroy` to prevent this kind of loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bit more confusing than I thought.

First of all, instead of using the websocket service shown above, I used this one: https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-websocket

The memory leak still persisted, but I noticed that, during the canvas updating process, there was a reference to an `imageObj.src` that was not being garbage collected.

Chrome, opera and firefox seem to keep used memory between reasonable limits now.